# How to take object style (pen, brush, symbol) in MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, style, mapbasic

How can I take style from existing object?
Brush from region, symbol from point?

In MapBasic documentation and in Google I can find only how to change object's style but can't find how to take it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ObjectInfo() function to access a number of "attributes" from the spatial objects, this also includes the styles:

```
Fetch First From Selection
symCurrent = ObjectInfo(Selection.OBJ, OBJ_INFO_SYMBOL)
```

In the example above you read the symbol style from the selected object using the Selection.